# Is it possible to take pictures for a timelapse on a Nikon D90 without using an intervalmeter

Tags: timelapse, nikon-d90

I'd like to put together a timelapse piece, but I don't have an intervalmeter. Is this something I can achieve with my Nikon D90 using my android phone or windows pc?

Comment: Is there anything that makes manually activating a wired cable release using a stopwatch unacceptable? What degree of precision do you need?

Comment: You could try whether your camera is supported by software such as DigiCamControl which can be used to take timelapses.

Answer (score 1):

Frame challenge…

How long is your total time-lapse to cover?
Intervalometer, tenner from eBay, batteries will last months. Phone/PC, [even though you already own them] batteries will last ~1 day.
Also - what happens if your phone rings?

Comment: A couple of hours. I know I probably need to get an intervalmeter but it's more to see if there is any way round it as a stop gap

Comment: I found this - https://www.tethertools.com/camera/nikon-d90/ - I can't recommend anything specifically as I use an intervalometer;-) [I also have neither a Win PC nor Android, I'm Mac/iPhone]

Answer (score 0):

There are several inexpensive interval timers, around $20 US or less, so there is hardly any reason not to get one.

Here is one for D90:
[https://www.amazon.com/Neewer-Digital-Shutter-Release-Replacement/dp/B005LTH7QA/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=mc-dc2+d90&qid=1592431501&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005LTH7QA)

This is seemingly a knock off of the Nikon MC-36a timer that is $160. Or possibly the same chip in it now?   This same item comes labeled as several brand names, and with connecting cables for different cameras, and most of them are not over $20. The D90 uses Nikons MC-DC2 cable, so the timer should specify MC-DC2 or D90.

Comment: Note that the item you linked to is currently unavailable.  So in reality to probably no longer exists.  But I saw another similar one that is apparently available https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07PN8SF19

Answer (score -1):

Please do research beforehand, here is a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSMHGEngnrg) to a YouTube video that uses an android device to control time lapses. I hope that answers your question.